# how to change datasource connection url dynamically in Jboss 6

Tags: java, jpa, jboss

I am using Jboss AS6 with container manager tracsaction.
Normally I am using a single MYSQL data source defined in mysql-ds.xml.
Now I have an user requirement that multiple users can have different database contents.So I am planning to create a new database for each user.In the future I can change my database design. But now for  a quick solution, I need to find a way to crossover between different databases.

this is my default configuration. I need to change **dbname**

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>DefaultDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://144.0.0.1:3306/**dbname**</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password>password</password>

    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
    <connection-property name="readOnly">false</connection-property>
  <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
  <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
    <maxReconnects>0</maxReconnects>
    <initialTimeout>15</initialTimeout>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- should only be used on drivers after 3.22.1 with "ping" support
<valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
-->
    <!-- sql to call when connection is created
<new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
  -->
    <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - MySQLValidConnectionChecker is preferred for newer drivers
<check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
  -->
</local-tx-datasource>
```

I am using Container manager transcaction.I need to find a way to change connection-url of my data source configuration.Then clear entity manager to connect new database.Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

For your task you actually can just hold multiple (5 in your case) persistence contexts. Then you link to appropriate context by choosing it according to the user name for example. This is the simpliest solution. It would work but all 5 contexts would be open and hold connection. Maybe it's what you need: from one hand this context are always ready for use and don't need to be warmed.

Another option is to construct persistence conext manually like in Java SE envirionment. This can be helpful if you are not able to hold many resources and switching is not so regular (once a day. for example).

You can find a lot of articles describing how to use JPA in Java SE environment. You are able to use them nearly in the same manner (so you will not use container injection mechanism, but find Persistnece Context through raw JNDI)

https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-tutorial-setting-jpa-java
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SettingUpJPA/SettingUpJPA.htm

Comment: You say that this is not possible dynamically in Jboss.?

Comment: It is possible but is not standard solution. Because of that you have 2 choices: plug in 5 persistence contexts or instantiate them manually when they are needed.

Another option is to use Multitenancy feature of Java EE/ But it is an advanced solution, and I'm not sure it's available in code. As I remember sush feature was planned to be included in Java EE 7/8.

And as I know it's has not been released yet. Anyway it will requiere merging your databses into single one with special partitioning on middleware level.

Comment: You actually are not clear in what you want as a result of your tryings. If you want to quickly and automatically switch configuratuion for the whole server - I think it is not possible at least with standard products including JBoss.
In any case you (if I understand right) need to hold some separate connections to some separate databases. So JBoss provies you such ability: customize several persistance contexts and go on. Then it is very simple to inject 5 EntityManager instances for each context and switch between them bery simple.

Comment: Why you say 5 persistence context ? I have not specified it

Comment: Actually for one time, I only need connections from one database. So I have to change connection-url of my data source. If I need 5 database connections, I would define 5 datasources and 5 persistence context. But What I need to change connection-url dynamically.Actually I want to succeed first one. Change configuration for a whole server

Comment: What is the purpose of switching connections dynamically? You say "change connection-url" dynamically. This usually means you drop your previous connection and pick antoher one. I described you 2 way of achieving this. You have all connections instantiated and just switch them. Or you connect in runtime in JavaSE manner.

Comment: I've just remembered another one but very bad way. You can customize your server from application through for example JMX. This can be used in Glassfish. Don't know about JBoss. But I recomend not to use this way.
In case of fail safe connection prepare them on start-up (in config). And use if required. We do so with LDAP connections in our project.

Comment: The first advice is not solution for me.Because I do not know number of databases. Second solution is not also solution for me. BEcause I am an enterprise application. And Now I am using all functionalities of entity manager. Also this implementation is a feature for only one customer. So it seems it is a little bit hard to achieve this.

Comment: You want to implement something non standard. In Java EE world of standards it's not unusual to achieve flexibilty solution with pain. And datasources in JEE are not single connections but entire connection pools wich are optimized for connecting to a single DB but in parallel. It's hard to reconnect them to another destination.

Comment: How about using File based db? Copy latest database to where datasource connection-url points. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I's hard to make it work right. If you hold connection to DB it's contents is probably cached (95% sure). If you swap the files under connection it would broke the DB state and probably DB itself. I think the best way is either hold many connection and switch among them or reconnect to other DS constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like:

```
<connection-url>${connectionURL:jdbc:mysql://144.0.0.1:3306/xyz}</connection-url>
```

and then pas the -DconnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://144.0.0.1:3306/abc to the standalone.sh/bat